# HIbernate query taking very long time

Tags: java, hibernate, optimization

I am trying optimize my code. I fetching the data using Hibernate, when I am running the query directly on the database it fetching the results in 2secs, rowcount around 2800. Same query when I fire from my Java code takes 8 secs. I have included the code snippet below.

```
Session hSession =openSession();
Query query = hsession.createSQLQuery(searchString); 
List results = query.list(); // it takes 7 secs to execute
```

I am not sure what is wrong over here.

Comment: what do you mean by directly on the database? on the same node? may be the network a problem?

Comment: If I run the query(searchString) in the queryAnalyser(IDE for MSSQL), it will get executed in 2 sec and I will get my result.

Comment: If you want we help you, you must show your mapping and your "searchString". We can not guess what is happening unless you provide more info.

Comment: ru sure that the problem is in the third line and not in the open session. I would print out the query and post it here. also I would make sure that third line is causing the problem.